Spring vulnerability issue
I am using spring boot 3.2.5 and in theeadfix scan it is showing vulnerable, so I have upgraded to 3.2.11 because other versions are showing vulnerabilities. When I upgraded to 3.2.11, it is internally using spring framework 6.1.14 and it is giving vulnerable like 6.1.14 internally referring 6.1.13 jars. I am not sure how this is happening.
Is it expected behavior?

which build tool do you use? can you share e.g. the dependency tree?

I am using gradle build tool. But strange behavior is how spring-web-6.1.14 is showing vulnerability in version 6.1.13. in local if I do ./gradllew depencies, I am getting only 6.1.14
